# SQL query group by distinct field, order by other fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, distinct

I have the following SQL string:

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT distinct local_insurer, subsidiary, location FROM T_WILMA WHERE PARENT=" & lParent_ID & _
                    " AND ACC_YEAR=" & lAcc_Year_ID & " AND ZOMBIE = FALSE GROUP BY local_insurer ORDER BY " & _
                    "subsidiary ASC, location ASC;"
```

Access throws an error because I cannot do this.
What I need is all records with a distinct local insurer, but in alphabetical order of the subsidiary and location fields.
Somehow, I never seem to get the right results.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY local_insurer` from the query. (`distinct` will ensure you get only unique combinations of values.)

Comment: I'm sorry Mark, but it turns out that it didn't give me the expected result after all. By removing the group by, I get the same insurer multiple times in the result, while I need every insurer to display only once, while sorting by the other criteria...

Comment: @KimGysen: I was assuming that either (a) you would only have one subsidiary and location for a given insurer, or (b) you would want to see all combinations of subsidiary and location for each insurer. If you can have multiple combinations of subsidiary and location for each insurer, but you only want to see one row per insurer, then what criteria do you want to use to determine which subsidiary and location should be returned for each insurer?

Comment: Indeed there can be multiple subsidiaries / locations for the same insurer. The context is that there are two queries: 1) query that loops through the entire t_wilma table (to make calculations on the resulting set) 2) the query described in my question; The two result sets will ultimately result into: "If oRst![local_insurer] = oRst2![local_insurer] Then to perform specific calculations. BUT, in the end the administrators want to have the resulting output report in a specific order, which means that I have to sort both queries in the correct order from the start.

Comment: To say, I have to work on existing code now. The alternative would be to re-write a considerable time consuming piece code; however getting the right output of this query sorted based on these parameters would save my day.

Comment: @KimGysen: So, what criteria do you want to use to determine which subsidiary and location should be returned for each insurer?

Comment: You just made me realize that sorting on this query doesn't make any sense at all with multiple subsidiaries.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting the error is because you did not include all the fields in the SELECT in GROUP BY. For example , if you SELECT a,b,c , you need to GROUP BY a,b,c (or c,b,a...) .

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT distinct local_insurer, subsidiary, location FROM T_WILMA WHERE PARENT=" & lParent_ID & _
                " AND ACC_YEAR=" & lAcc_Year_ID & " AND ZOMBIE = FALSE GROUP BY local_insurer, subsidiary, location ORDER BY " & _
                "subsidiary ASC, location ASC;"
```

Comment: I need distinct values on the local_insurer only. Turns out I didn't find an answer yet anyway.